# In eclipse how to run .css file.. if i run .css file as run on server the source code is opening in note pad. can any one help me

Tags: html, css, eclipse

How can I run a .css file using Eclipse?

If I run a .css file using "run on server", the source code is opening in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't usually run a CSS file. You need to attach it to your mark up using the link tag, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/path/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a CSS file. 
It is a resource a browser can interprete when rending html, which references the css.

What you can do is running a webserver in eclipse and let this provide the css. But this depends on the kind of your project.

For example when it is a Java EE Project and you use the WTP stuff, then you can configure Java EE server runtimes and you can define your project as deployable.

If you are doing php stuff, then normaly you have an external environment like wamp stuff. Where it depends on your configuration how your project resources are placed in the webserver.

So please provide a more specific question, next time.